# Why are free vortices irrotational?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

In free vortices (such as water draining in a sink) the molecules away from the center axis will be irrotational.  Why is this the case in terms of how the forces on the individual molecules differ from a rotational vortex case?